# How to Pair two index in Multi-dimensional List and Match with others

Tags: python, ip, tcpdump

*By using tcpdump output data I want to create a script that it summarizes* **source-destination IP, start-stop time, how many packets found, what sum of packet length**

Currently, to accomplish this I created a multi-dimensional list which have the data like following and extracted from tcpdump

```
[['10.247.15.39', '172.217.2.161', '13:25:31', '46'], ['10.247.15.39', '172.217.2.163', '13:25:31', '46'], ['172.217.2.161', '10.247.15.39', '13:25:31', '0'],...
```

There are over 3000 entry

Now I need the find other entries which have same **source** and **destination IP** then when match found let's say 10 matches found it will for that specific pair

I want it to summarize like this

**Desired Output:**

```
Source: 151.101.125.140     dest: 10.247.15.39  start:13:25:31 
stop:13:25:35 package amount:10  total length: 1965482
```

Start and stop time determined based on find and last package found time

And I want it to keep repeat same process for every pair of source and destination IP so basically it will **create a summary list for me to take look at it and view if there is too much traffic happened between two IP**

But I don't have any idea how I can pair two indexes and search for matches in the list.

I thought doing something like

```
filtered_list = []
i = 0
i_2 = 1
try:
    while i <= len(parse_output):
        if parse_output[i][0] == parse_output[i_2][0]:
            print("source ip same")
            if parse_output[i][1] == parse_output[i_2][1]:
                print("destination same")
        i = i + 1
        i_2 = i + 1
except IndexError:
```

But just my brain stopped if you can help me I would be glad

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is your question here? Can you provide desired output next to actual output?

Comment: Just tried to fix it I hope it's good now and clear

Comment: You keep on saying package but I think you mean packet?

Comment: Sorry just fixed it , the reason why ı am saying packet this informations in list extracted from tcpdump

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "I need to find all of them then based on that find start and finish time"

Comment: So each 4 value connected to each other and have time and same ip pattern can appear more than one because thats indicator communication continues so I need tl detect first and last packet and get first packet time as start time and get last packet time as finish time

Comment: I am a network automation engineer and would be glad to help. What is the file extension type? I will build out the code for you.

Comment: Yepram, thank you so much for your help offer. So file extension type is txt which is output of tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Reposting the (modified) code you had in your initial question, as it's relevant here:

```py
parse_output = [
    '10.247.15.39', '172.217.2.161', '13:25:31', '46',
    '10.247.15.39', '172.217.2.163', '13:25:31', '46',
    '172.217.2.161', '10.247.15.39', '13:25:31', '0'
]
for i in range(0, len(parse_output), 4):
    newlist = []
    newlist.append("source: " + parse_output[i] +
        " destination: " + parse_output[i + 1] +
        " time: " + parse_output[i + 2] + 
        " package size: "+ parse_output[i + 3])
    print(newlist)
```

Which produces this output:

```sh
['source: 10.247.15.39 destination: 172.217.2.161 time: 13:25:31 package size: 46']
['source: 10.247.15.39 destination: 172.217.2.163 time: 13:25:31 package size: 46']
['source: 172.217.2.161 destination: 10.247.15.39 time: 13:25:31 package size: 0']
```

The target is `['source: 10.247.15.39 destination: 172.217.2.161 time: 13:25:31 number of packet:5 total packet size: 46']`, which includes the two IPs, timestamp, number of packets and total packet size of the first packet.

#### Solution

All of the information we need except for the length is present in the first packet, so there is no need for a for loop. There are 4 pieces of data per packet, so the number of packets can be got by dividing the length of `parse_input` by 4. In this example, create 12 "packets" as input data.

```
packet = ['10.247.15.39', '172.217.2.161', '13:25:31', '46']
parse_output = 12*packet
number_of_packets = int(len(parse_output)/4)
total_packet_size = sum([int(i) for i in parse_output[3::4]])
newlist = [
    "source: " + parse_output[0] +
    " destination: " + parse_output[1] +
    " start: " + parse_output[2] +
    " stop: " + parse_output[-2] +
    " number of packets:" + str(number_of_packets) +
    " total packet size: " + str(total_packet_size)
]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: You should change your question (i.e. add parts of these comments) so it is clear what you mean

Comment: Just rewrite it I hope it's clear now thank you Ross for your help